# How does this NTFS Bug work?

Tags: ntfs

A while back, (about 1 month ago), I submitted an NTFS DoS vulnerability on exploit-db. It got accepted and is currently on the website, but I do not quite understand how the vulnerability works, and why it does not work on Windows 10.

The bug references C:/$MFT in html.
`<img src="C:\$MFT">`. Once this code is in a webpage, anyone not running higher than Windows 8.1 will crash. This could even apply to this post, but of course it isnt, as this website allows for HTML code in a post.

How does this bug work? What causes the system to crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the system is crashing because he is endlessly trying to read the path, and every other programme running are stuck because they are waiting to access the NTFS drive but they cannot  since the web browser is already trying.

Comment: Sort of. The browser calls a function that is not normally called by other file operations, which results in a write-lock being put on $MFT, which then prevents kernel threads from performing file table operations, eventually resulting in a stuck thread bugcheck (BSoD).

Comment: How come this does not work on Windows 10?